# Как сделать, чтобы выданные рандомные числа вносились в список?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, for

```
import random
p = []

a = int(input("Сколько раз?: "))

for gg in range(a):
    hf = random.randrange (1, 100, 1)
    print (hf)


p.append(hf)

print(p)
```

Comment: Внести append внутрь цикла

Answer (score 4):

Как сказал @MBo

```
import random
p = []

a = int(input("Сколько раз?: "))

for gg in range(a):
    hf = random.randrange (1, 100, 1)
    print (hf)
    p.append(hf)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, назовите переменные осмысленно. И напишите комментарии с помощью `#ваш комментарий.`

```
import random 
ourlist = []

quantity = int(input("Сколько раз?: ")) #спрашиваем у пользователя сколько раз с помощью input()

for i in range(quantity): #цикл for. Тут можно назвать переменную i, так как это цикл.
    randomnum = random.randint (1, 100) #выбирает случайное число.
    print (randomnum) 
    ourlist.append(randomnum) #добавляем в список list переменную randomnum. Ваша ошибка была
    #именно тут, вы забыли поставить отступ и добавлялось только последнее число i.

print(ourlist)
```

программа
намного красивее стала.

Comment: 1) Называть переменную ключевым словом языка Python - это тоже как-то как-то ;)  Я имею в виду `list = ...`. 2) Просто "переводить" строки типа `import random` на русский с помощью комментариев - это вовсе не те комментарии, которые нужны в программе %)  3) Длинные комментарии лучше писать над строкой, а не справа - их там просто не видно, они уезжают за экран и толку от них поэтому нет. Но основное, конечно - это не пишите банальных комментариев, которые просто дублируют код, так не надо делать. Комментарии не для этого придуманы.

Comment: @CrazyElf я знаю, но сейчас в комментариях я поясняю код для человека, который может этого не понимает (то есть не для профи, а для новичка)

Comment: Ладно, насчёт комментариев для новичка убедили, но всё же больно это всё видеть. А первый пункт - так вообще типичные грабли, на которых тут регулярно пляшут начинающие, судя по регулярным вопросам. Тщательнее надо )

Comment: @CrazyElf вы имели виду комментарий ```#импортируем необходимый модуль random.```? Исправил

Comment: Главное - исправьте таки переменную `list` на что-нибудь другое. Иначе потом сюрприз будет, если дальше по коду будет что-то типа `print(list(range(10)))` и человек не поймёт, почему вдруг Python ругается на ровном месте.

Comment: @CrazyElf сделано!

Answer (score 1):

Не надо применят цикл для генерирования заданного количества случайных чисел:

```
import random

a = int(input("Сколько раз?: "))
p = random.choices(range(1, 100), k=a) 
print(p)
```

*Объяснение:*

Функция `random.choices()` принимает в ключевом параметре `k=` желаемое количество случайных чисел и возвращает прямо их список.